# calculating length of concatenated string in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I need to check the length of strings before displaying it inline or in a newline. I am using following code.

```xml
<s:if test='!#person.x && !#person.y'>                          
    <s:if test='#person.firstName!=null && #person.lastName !=null && %{(#person.firstName)(#person.lastName).length() > 25}'>
        <s:text name="#person.firstName"></s:text><br>
        <s:text name="#person.lastName"></s:text>
        <s:if test='#person.suffixName!=null && #person.suffixName!=""'>
            &nbsp;<s:text name="#person.suffixName"></s:text>   
        </s:if>,</s:if>
        &nbsp;<s:text name="#person.age"></s:text><br/>
    </s:if>
</s:if>
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: It is NOT what your code (that has syntax errors) does. Please improve your question with working code and full explanation of what you want, what instead you achieve, and what have you tried

Comment: Do you want a length of `firstName` or `lastName` or the length of both together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function in POJO of `person` class

```
  private String getFullName(){
      return firstName+lastName;
  }
```

And use it in jsp as below `%{#person.fullName.length() > 25}'`

```
<s:if test='!#person.x && !#person.y'>                          
<s:if test='#person.firstName!=null && #person.lastName !=null && %{#person.fullName.length() > 25}'>
    <s:text name="#person.firstName"></s:text><br>
    <s:text name="#person.lastName"></s:text>
    <s:if test='#person.suffixName!=null && #person.suffixName!=""'>
        &nbsp;<s:text name="#person.suffixName"></s:text>   
    </s:if>,</s:if>
    &nbsp;<s:text name="#person.age"></s:text><br/>
</s:if>
</s:if>
```